# ed(1) adds ^M to every line of my file

Tags: shell, wordpress, ed

I am working on automating a WordPress install. While editing wp-config.php file, I need to replace 8 lines containing `put your unique phrase here` with Salt generated by WordPress.org servers.

So, I used the top answer from [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233398/download-and-insert-salt-string-inside-wordpress-wp-config-php-with-bash) which tells me to run this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

SALT=$(curl -L https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)
STRING='put your unique phrase here'
printf '%s\n' "g/$STRING/d" a "$SALT" . w | ed -s wp-config.php
```

This works just fine, as it replaces the required lines with proper salt. However, it also appends a `^M` at the end of every string in wp-config.php, except the newly added ones.

Now it looks like this:

```
 */^M
^M
define('AUTH_KEY',         '|%)Y1>vzXGRbE?`FFZX3Mq|ur?tN/,R&%@)juSc?f@bNPYm~P=aF&Fl?!HGF4V}a');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '6;KHO6=[<daU7t|]dA`Ta-h7.2B@3Sa`daIinz/6!O=GQWE(@r(<3L+X,/:[du%Q');
/**
**/^M
^M
/**^M
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.^M
```

I don't know much about ed(1), so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the carriage returns were not already there?

Comment: I am sure it wasn't there before.
Just for reference, I am using git bash on Windows to ssh into the Ubuntu 18.04 servers. But I have never faced this issue before, I have used this setup for years.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the original file, prior to you running the script?  If so, please post the first few lines of `od -b wp-config.php`.  I suspect you'll find that the `^M` (015) was there all along, but your editor interpreted them as DOS line-endings, while the script has inserted a unix-style line.

Comment: I have a copy of the original file and it doesn't have an ^M in the beginning.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
```

Comment: What text editor are you using to open/view the file?  Some editors will hide those bytes because they are DOS-style line-endings, and only show them after a non-conforming line has been added (by `ed`).  You'll need to include a binary representation of (the start of) the file, using a hex dumper or the `od` command I suggested earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series of commands that you mention in the question does not add carriage-returns (the `^M` things) to your text file.

However, if the file already had carriage-returns at the end of each line, which all DOS text files have, then it would have added non-DOS lines to the file, which means that the text file, after editing, has some lines that are Unix text lines and some lines that are DOS text lines.  Whatever editor you are viewing the file in then has to try to figure out what to do with this and decides to show it as a Unix text file, with the carriage-returns displayed as `^M` (`vim` would do this, for example).

The solution is to run `dos2unix` on your `wp-config.php` file.  It would be able to handle the mixed types of lines and would convert the whole file to a Unix text file.

Also note that the `ed` editing script will not *cleanly* replace the string `put your unique phrase here` in the document.  Given the document

```
000
AAA
put your unique phrase here
BBB
XXX
```

... the command sequence would generate

```
000
AAA
BBB
define('AUTH_KEY',...
...
XXX
```

(note the location of the `BBB` line before and after). To fix this so that the `define` lines are added before `BBB` in the text above, change the `a` command to an `i` command, i.e. *insert before the current line* rather than append after (the "current line" will be the `BBB` line since that line is right after the line that the `g//d` command has modified).

Comment: Thanks for the dos2unix recommendation! It fixed my issue.
The unique pharse thing is working as intended, it removes the entire like that has the `put your unique phrase here` experssion in it, and replaces it with `define('AUTH KEY', ...`